# How to send an email to Inbox using emailjs, Every time email is landing to SPAM

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, npm

Below is the code i am using to send an email using emailjs npm but it is always landing on spam. Help me to write a code which will always send an email to inbox

```
 var email = require('emailjs');
 var server     = email.server.connect({
 user:  "no-reply@domain.com", 
 password:"password", 
 host:  "mailserver", 
 ssl: true
 });

 var message    = {
 text:  "i hope this works", 
 from:  "Company Name <no-reply@domain.com>", 
 to:        "someone <username@gmail.com>",
 subject:   "testing emailjs",

 attachment: 
 [
   {data:"<html>i <i>hope</i> this works!</html>", 
 alternative:true}
  ]
  };

  // send the message and get a callback with an error or details of 
  the message that was sent
   server.send(message, function(err, message) { console.log(err || 
   message); });
```

Comment: If you're really using `no-reply@domain.com` as your from address, your email is possibly failing SPF checks. You might check the headers of the email file and look for header(s) talking about an SPF check.

Comment: changed the email address ... still it is going to spam

Comment: I guess its going to spam because you send html emails and the spam filter does not trust your server. Just trust your clients that they will move the emails out of the spam folder because they like the content, then it won't be filtered out on other clients.

Comment: @JrDuvvuri There is no reliable way to avoid the spam filter, otherwise every single spammer would be using it. Even serious, long established websites mention to check the spam folder when they have just sent out an email.

Comment: It can help your chances of not getting marked as spam to use some of the pay services out there, such as AWS SES. They will walk you through a setup process to make sure your SPF rules are correct, and to get your emails DKIM signed...and I think they work pretty hard to keep their SMTP server reputations high.